# Clean request.data in django rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Quick question:

I know that Django has some baked-in security at different system levels, but I'm not sure if accessing the the `request.data` property directly safe? (can it cause a security vulnerability by simply reading the users input data before i have done something to clean it)

```
book = Book.objects.get(uuid=request.data.uuid)
```

(obviously, this is a simplified example)

Do I have to clean the data? Are there some packages that do this for me or can I use some of Django's native functions for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned you are using django rest framework, you should use the serializers for that.

Have a look at:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

```py
serializer = MySerializer(data=request.data)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

Comment: why? what are the security implications? Are model managers open to XSS attacks or alike?

Comment: This is to sanitize the data transported via XHR. So there is a validator for uuids for instance. This makes sure evil scripts are not injected in your database.

Comment: I'd argue that you didn't answer nor even addressed the question at all. The question was whether it's safe to access the `request` body directly. You proposed a way that doesn't involve accessing the req body directly. Your answer has little to do with the actual question. In fact, serializer fields sanitize the input somewhat. That doesn't mean the same logic doesn't also exist e. g. on the data access layer. I think it's best if we leave our argument as is and I wait for different answers.

Comment: You question is probably a bit misguided by your understanding of web security in general. XSS attacks happen on the client, usually javascript injected in the database and later on interpreted by the client. So yes it is safe to access `.data`, your backend code won't interpret this code. It's data, unless you'd use something like `eval` there no way any malicious code would be interpreted on the server side. What you have to make sure of is that you inputs are validated both on the client and sever side. Anything coming from the database should be sanitized on the client side.

Comment: If you are building a ""traditional" Django project the way to do that is to use Django forms and the validate methods on the django models. If you are building a SPA or a mobile app, then you've probably already added rest framework extension and the way to validate data for "unsafe" requests is serializers. So using serializers to validate data is the way you will prevent XSS....

Comment: What is MySerializer here. From where can I import MySerializer. I have already imported from rest_framework import serializers